# Whitespace between nested list

Tags: css

I'm building a website, but encountered a little problem.
I have created a nested list with html, but I want to see some whitespace between choices.

```
             <ul>
                <li>Mini onderhoud
                    <ul>
                        <li>Computer stofvrij maken.</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Klein onderhoud
                    <ul>
                        <li>Computer stofvrij maken.</li>
                        <li>Computer controleren op malware (virussen, spyware, adware, trojans, ...).</li>
                        <li>Opruimen van onnodige software en bestanden.</li>
                        <li>Computer controleren op fouten.</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Groot onderhoud
                    <ul>
                        <li>Computer stofvrij maken.</li>
                        <li>Computer controleren op malware (virussen, spyware, adware, trojans, ...).</li>
                        <li>Opruimen van onnodige software en bestanden.</li>
                        <li>Computer controleren op fouten.</li>
                        <li>Backup maken van alle bestanden.</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Deluxe onderhoud
                    <ul>
                        <li>Computer stofvrij maken.</li>
                        <li>Computer formatteren en Windows herinstalleren.</li>
                        <li>Software (o.a. Microsoft Office, anti-virus, firewall, ...) herinstalleren.</li>
                        <li>Backup maken van alle bestanden.</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

How do I get some whitespace between each first li element? So, I need whitespace between Mini onderhoud and Klein onderhoud, between Klein onderhoud en Groot onderhoud, and so on.
I tried with br, but this is not XHTML 1.1 Strict.
Any other solutions?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Assign the `<li>` elements with a class name.

`<li class="spacing">`

Add a css style:

```
li.spacing {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that was easier than I thought.
Thank you very much Sir!

Comment: @Ashwin: Look at the other answers for a solution without extra classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use css anc classes - you could assign a class of (say) "toplevel" to your top level `<li>` items that you want to give the spacing to, then in your css have:

```
.toplevel li {margin:0 0 5px 0;}
```

Comment: This will style **all** `li` s and not only the top level ones.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want:

```
li { 
  margin-bottom: 1em; /* or what ever */
}

li li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the first(parent) ul 
`<ul class="navi">`
and then add a css style

```
ul.navi > li{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: The > is a child selector so this rule only matches the "onderhoud" elements.